# PHP data to JSON for d3 chart

Tags: php, json, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm creating a simple d3 chart which is linked to data from a MySQL server (with PHP handling those queries). I've formatted the data in PHP to be JSON compliant, and finally used the PHP function json_encode to pass the data to javascript. Below, I've included the important lines of code:

1) The packer array is created in JSON format and is d3-friendly too.

```
$packer[] = array('key' => $subject, 'values' => $array);
//where $subject is a string and $array is (you guessed it) an array of data
```

2) In the d3 chart constructor, data is initialized as an array, in JSON format

```
var data = <?=json_encode($packer)?>;
//here, I echo the php array to javascript in JSON format
```

When I load the page, the chart appears, but no data is loaded. I therefore know this problem lies in the loading of the data. I'd appreciate any help!

EDIT: I found the answer! It was a problem with my JSON data using arrays but d3 required an object formatted slightly differently. Link for those curious:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500742/plotting-json-data-using-nvd3

```
$temp['values'][$i]['x']= $i;
$temp['values'][$i]['y']= intval($row['temperature']);
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Did you check the generated data?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.

The console is clear. As for generated data, it looks fine. Here's what the PHP generates (what is shows in the javascript after the server executes the PHP):

[{"key":"twitter","values":[[0,0],[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]}]

Comment: I dont know so much about PHP, but could it be a timing issue? Say that you are generating the chart via d3 but the data has not finished loading? Try to figure out (with Browser dev tools debugger or console.log(data)) whether the data is there when you are calling the d3-stuff for generating the chart.